# Trying to use Selenium web-driver / PhantomJS in Python3. Only working for http?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

As the title says, i'm trying to use `PhantomJS` with `Selenium web-driver` in `python3`, however all attempts at getting `PhantonJS` to even connect to SSL/TLS websites has returned nothing but `HTML` tags and a blank screenshot?
I tried any possible solution i've found in regards to this problem however none of them have rectified the issue for me. Is `PhantomJS` broken or am i missing something here?

(CODE EXAMPLE)
(GNU/Linux)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
)
try:

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
    driver.set_window_size(2000, 1500)
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    driver.save_screenshot('/root/Desktop/screen.png')

except Exception as E:
    print(E)
```